# Including html template in servlet

Tags: java, html, jakarta-ee, servlets

I want to include header and footer template in my servlet, like this in PHP in a PHP controller :

```
public doSomething()
{
    include "header.html";
    //generate doSomething content in HTML and echo it
    include "footer.html";
}
```

*PS : It's an example, i don't do directly like this in PHP ;)*

In this way, I want to avoid like this in all JSP files (the includes) :

```
<jsp:include page="header.html" />
<%-- Display doSomething informations -->
<jsp:include page="footer.html" />
```

So exactly, I want :

```
public void doGet( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response )
throws ServletException, IOException {
    //Include the header.html
    this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher( "/WEB-INF/Example.jsp" ).forward( request, response );
    //Include the footer.html
}
```

Here, I want to include footer and header to do not do this into JSP.

Comment: what you want exactly?

Comment: After forwarding to `Example.jsp` both header and footer html will be included in this jsp.

Comment: Yes but I'm asking if I can include header and footer in Servlet and not JSP file.

Comment: One option is read them into string and set them as request attributes and use those attributes in jsp or write those strings in to response and call request dispatcher's `include` method.

Comment: Thank you @RP- , is that I want.

Answer (score 0):

So RP anwsert this question in the comments,, but to give this question an actual anwser i copied his into here:

"*One option is read them into string and set them as request attributes and use those attributes in jsp or write those strings in to response and call request dispatcher's include method.*" - RP